# Map projection in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps, coordinate-system, wgs84

I want to overlay some data whose projection is WGS-84 on Google map layer in OpenLayers. But I just can't make them in the right place. I did as follows:

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {           
        numZoomLevels: 20,
        projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
        displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG: 4326")
        });
googlelayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google street", {sphericalMercator: true});
map.addLayer(googlelayer);
veclayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("vector", {
                                    projection: map.displayProjection
                                    };
var geojson_format = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON();
veclayer.addFeatures(geojson_format.read(jsonData));
```

Though I have assigned `veclayer` in 4326 projection, but it is still interpreted as 900913, and the display coordination system is also 900913, though I set displayProjection to 4326. What mistake do I make?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm a big fan of "preFeatureInsert"....

```
var veclayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("vector", {
           projection: map.displayProjection,
           preFeatureInsert: function(feature) {
           feature.geometry.transform(projWGS84,proj900913);
           }
        });
```

Comment: Aha, it works! Thank you very much. But I wonder what the property `preFeatureInsert` means, anyhow, I can't find it in the official API doc~

Comment: As far as im concerned, it transforms the projections as defined, before the feature is inserted... Nice and generic, and no need for conversion functions etc.

Answer (score 6):

You have a space after the colon.   `Projection("EPSG: 4326")` should actually be `Projection("EPSG:4326")`, no space before `4326`.

Comment: Haha it really works! I mean for the display projection. However, the overlaid data is still not in the right place (the same wrong place as before). Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```
               map = new OpenLayers.Map('map',
                { numZoomLevels: 19,
                  units: 'm',
                  eventListeners: {"moveend": update_movend},
                  projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
                  displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")

                });

        OpenLayers.Projection.addTransform("EPSG:4326", "EPSG:900913", OpenLayers.Layer.SphericalMercator.projectForward);
        OpenLayers.Projection.addTransform("EPSG:900913", "EPSG:4326", OpenLayers.Layer.SphericalMercator.projectInverse);


        var layerMapnik = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM.Mapnik("Mapnik");
        var layerTah = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM.Osmarender("Osmarender");

        var gphy = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
            "Google Physical",
            {
                type: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
            }
        );
//        gphy = map.projection;

        var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
            "Google Streets",
            {
                numZoomLevels: 20,
            }
        );
        //gmap = map.projection;

        layerMapnik.projection = map.projection;
        layerTah.projection = map.projection;

        vectors = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Vector Layer");

          var help_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Waypoints", {
             projection: map.displayProjection,
             strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
         });
```

I posted my old code snippet. I remember that the clou is in the projections. addTransform should solve your problem. (proj4)

Comment: Thank you for your help. But it seems not to work

Answer (score 1):

You may fall there because you are looking for a slightly offset vector representation on Google Maps while it's fine on other base layers and transforming EPSG:4326 to EPSG:900913 or EPSG:3857 doesn't solve everything.

There is a bug on Google Maps that doesn't evaluate well the div size when initiating the OpenLayers Map object if it's not yet visible. So after the transform() & redraw() calls, you may need to do `myMapObject.updateSize();` to let Google know the actual proportion of your map on screen.

If you are looking for a generic solution to transform layers from one projection to another, you could use this function:

```
var myMap = new OpenLayers.Map('mapDiv');

function mapBaseLayerChanged(evtObj) {
  var mapProj, baseProj, map_this, newBase;
  map_this = this;
  newBase = evtObj.layer;
  mapProj = (map_this.projection && map_this.projection instanceof OpenLayers.Projection) ?
            map_this.projection : new OpenLayers.Projection(map_this.projection);
  baseProj = newBase.projection;
  if (!(baseProj.equals(mapProj))) {
     var center, maxExt;
     center = map_this.getCenter().transform(mapProj, baseProj);
     maxExt = newBase.maxExtent;
     map_this.projection = baseProj;
     map_this.maxExtent = maxExt;
     map_this.setCenter(center, map_this.getZoom(), false, true);
     // Transforms all sub-layers
     for (var i = 0; i < map_this.layers.length; i++) {
        if (map_this.layers[i].isBaseLayer == false) {
           map_this.layers[i].addOptions({projection: baseProj}, true);
           // Transforms all features of the vectors
           for (var j = 0; j < map_this.layers[i].features.length; j++) {
              map_this.layers[i].features[j].geometry.transform(mapProj, baseProj);
           }
           map_this.layers[i].redraw();
        }
     }
     //Solves Google's problem (and mine at the same occasion)
     map_this.updateSize();
  }
}
myMap.events.register('changebaselayer', myMap, mapBaseLayerChanged);
```

Et voilà!

Answer (score 0):

For Yahoo you can try these options:

```
baseLayerOptions:{
  sphericalMercator: true,
  maxExtent:new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.34,-20037508.34,20037508.34,20037508.34)
}
```