# OpenLayers LatLon conversion

Tags: openlayers-2, convert, coordinate-system

I have an OpenLayers map with a settings like a below. All LatLon points are represented like a `POINT(3684182 5207957)`. In a more usual form (for me) it looks like a `(104.287422, 52.284126)`. How can I "convert" "POINT(…)" to this form?

```
projection: "EPSG:4326"
actualBounds: "0,0,4938083,5375780"
bounds: "0,0,9248768,9248768"
initCenterCoord: "3791668,5149639"
initCenterZoom: "5"
maxExtent:
    bottom: -90
    left: -180
    right: 180
    top: 90
maxResolution: 36128
numZoomLevels: 10
resolution: 141.125
restrictedExtent:
    bottom: 1185098
    left: -4938083
    right: 9876166
    top: 11936658
utm:
    cityy: 9248768
    hemisphere: "N"
    inverseflattering: 298.2571644
    majorsemiaxis: 6378137
    offsetx: -1902571
    offsety: -2422059
    scalex: 100
    scaley: -100
    shiftx: -41454992
    shifty: 583328750
    zone: 48
```

Update: Some JS examples about a conversion between a projections:

```
> var projWGS84 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
> var proj900913 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");
> var point = new OpenLayers.LonLat(3684182, 5207957);
c
  lat: 5207957
  lon: 3684182
> point.transform(proj900913, projWGS84);
c
  lat: 5207957
  lon: 3684182
> point.transform(projWGS84, proj900913);
c
  lat: 5207957
  lon: 3684182
```

Update 2: PostGIS conversion from 900913 to 4326 do it wrong:

```
SELECT ST_AsText( ST_Transform( ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(3684182 5207957)', 900913) , 4326 ) );
------------------------------------------
 POINT(33.0955700007803 42.3128389015332)
```

Screeshot:
[image]

Comment: Thought: can these coordinates be measured from the boundaries of the map?

Comment: whatever projection your points are in it is not lat/lon - you'll need to check with your data provider to find out what it is.

Comment: Well, it is a WKT data, it can be normally readed via the OpenLayers.Format.WKT().read() and showed on the map. All I need, is to convert it into another look.

Comment: Ugh… It was my bad, I've missed an one small function, which converts data to a normal view.

When a self-answer timer will be turned off, I'll close this question.

Answer (score 5):

There is a [geometry].tranform( [current_projection] , [desired_projection] ) function that you can use.

You will need to know what the current projection of the geomtry is (probably SRID  ESPG:900913), and the projection you want (probably ESPG:4326).

The code would look something like this:

```
var projWGS84 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
var proj900913 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");

var someGeom = originalGeom.transform(proj900913  , projWGS84 );
```

Alternatively  when setting up your vector layer you can use something like [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17003/map-projection-in-openlayers/17013#17013), or of course a combination of the two.

EDIT:
Ive looked at your code and this seems to work for me:

```
var projWGS84 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
var proj900913 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");

var point = new OpenLayers.LonLat(3684182, 5207957);
var point2 =  point.transform(proj900913, projWGS84);
```

Comment: The problem is that this data already in the WGS84 projection. Here is a [link](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/spherical_mercator.html#reprojecting-points-bounds).

And also, a transformation between a WGS84 and 900913 does not do anything. It is still a (3684182 5207957)

Comment: Can you put the code in your question please.

Comment: Whoops, sorry. I've added examples into the question.

Comment: Well, I even took a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/Nt7fp.png
And also, updated a post with a PostGIS conversion example.

Comment: Whats the editor your using?

Comment: It is a Google Chrome web developer tools on the screenshot

Comment: Is it saying that every bit of code results in "undefined"?  If so, have you included the OpenLayers .js file?

Comment: No, any assignment in JS returns `undefined`. It is ok.
`OpenLayers.LatLon` objects are created successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I have had some problems converting from different projections previously. My approach has been to define all of the projections that I need at the top of a .`js` file so I am certain that they are, as I found the nomenclature confusing. The other issue I found was that no projection will occur, if a EPSG code that you reference does not exist.

```
//Define Projections
Proj4js.defs["EPSG:27700"]  = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs";
Proj4js.defs["EPSG:4326"]   = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs";
Proj4js.defs["EPSG:900913"] = "+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs";
```

Not sure if that is your problem, but it has helped me previously.

Comment: Well, nope. I had tried to use Javascript+OpenLayers, PostGIS and Python+pyproj (bindings to proj.4 library), and all results doesn't looks like a "Luke, you just need to convert it from EPSG:900913 to EPSG:4326".