# GeoJSON and OSM layers with different projection

Tags: openstreetmap, coordinate-system, geojson, openlayers-2

I have a GeoJSON from NaturalEarth for world state boundaries and I want to display it with only without backgroung. But also, I want to add a OSM layer as another baselayer option.

The code I am using is the following one, but when I check it, as OSM is in another projection, the center map does not work. However if I change the projection of "mapDiv" the one that does not work is the vector layer with the GeoJSON information.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var lon = 5;
    var lat = 40;
    var zoom = 5;
    var map;

    function Initialize(){
        // Map
     map = new OpenLayers.Map('mapDiv', {
            controls:[
                new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher()]
            } );

        // OSM          
        var osmLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("OSM");
        map.addLayer(osmLayer);

        // GeoJSON
        var geojsonLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("GeoJSON", {
            isBaseLayer: true,
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                url: "world_0.json",
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
            })
        });
        map.addLayer(geojsonLayer);

        // Options
        map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat), zoom);
    }

</script>
```

I have try something similar to [this example](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenLayers_osm_file_example), but I continue having problems when switching between the layers.

The GeoJSON has been created with SHP files from NaturalEarth with ogr2ogr command.

Comment: The problem is similar to [this one](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17003/map-projection-in-openlayers). But the solution does not work on this case

Comment: I found that a solution is to define the SRS during the conversion with **ogr2ogr** using following command: `ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:900913 xxxx.json yyyy.shp`. However, it will be great it someone could solve the problem without requiring the SRS change.

Comment: Try replacing `format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()` by `format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({
                'internalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
                'externalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
            });`

Comment: @gcarrillo your solution does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform your center point, use the internal and external Projection as cgarillo mentioned and then also define the Projection of your vectorLayer and your map:

```
var center_coord = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat).transform("EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857");
    map.setCenter(center_coord, zoom);

...

 var geojsonLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("GeoJSON", {
        projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857"),
....
```

http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/jbwx0au9/

(slightly different method to get the features here, but still the same things to do...)

Comment: That's correct @Thomas B. I transformed previously the center, but projection attribute of Vector Layer is the key. Can you explain why? I mean, why EPSG:3857 and EPSG:900913 are equivalent projections? And how could I know previously OSM projection for future problems?

Comment: 900913 is the unofficial Code for Google Sherical Mercator and 3857 the official one ;) http://docs.openlayers.org/library/spherical_mercator.html